# Flutter iOS build takes forever (with firebase dependencies)

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm making a small app using firebase/firestore to learn, and since adding the firebase components, build times have been insanely long for the iOS version of the App.

I've seen a few post mentionning that but I couldn't find definitive answers.
Any idea how to fix this? A clean build takes 10+ min, it's unusable.

Thanks in advance !

My pubspec.yaml's dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.5
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
  path_provider: ^2.0.12
  open_filex: ^4.3.2
```

Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: share `flutter doctor` output

Comment: @RohanJariwala done ! No issues except the java bundle thing which didn't cause problem before I added firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pre-built Firebase SDKs: Firebase provides pre-built SDKs for iOS that you can use in your Flutter project. This can help reduce build times as you won't have to build the Firebase SDKs yourself. You can find more information on how to use pre-built Firebase SDKs in the official documentation.

For example, you can check this repo for Firestore pre-built sdk

https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks

Comment: This most definitely fixed it. Build times went from 450+ seconds to about 50. Thanks !

Comment: You are most welcome @Tom ! Wish you all the best 